# Find the adjoint of $-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C R_z \ dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $L$ be a self adjoint linear operator (not necessarily bounded) and $C$ apositively oriented simple closed curve in the resolvent set encircling $\sigma_0 \subset \sigma(L)\subset \mathbb{R}$. Find the adjoint of $-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C R_z  \ dz$ where $R_z$ is the resolvent operator given by $R_z=(L-zI)^{-1}$.

Here is my attempt:

I know that $R_z^*=R_{\bar{z}}$ since $L$ is self adjoint. Then I want to say that $$\left(-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C R_z  \ dz\right)^*=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\overline{C}}R_{\overline{z}}\ dz.$$ (I "distributed the conjugate operator). However, I think that the integral operator should be self adjoint. How can I show this? Note that $\overline{C}$ is the complex conjugate of the curve $C$.

Other considerations:

I think I have shown that $\frac{-1}{2\pi i}\int_C R_z \ dz=-\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\overline{C}} R_z \ dz$ although I am not $100\%$ sure that this is correct.

Comment: on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvent_formalism we can read that if $C$ encircles only one eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $\frac{-1}{2 i \pi} \int_C (L-zI)^{-1} dz$ is the projection operator on the some subspace, namely the eigenspace associated with $\lambda$.

Comment: @user1952009 I in this case $C$ encircles a subset of the line (unless there is a typo in the original problem)

Comment: and for being 100% sure of what is the adjoint of your contour integral, you could explicitly define the integral : parametrize the contour $C(t), t \in [0,1]$, hence $\frac{-1}{2 i \pi} \int_C (L-zI)^{-1} dz = \frac{-1}{2 i \pi}  \int_0^1 (L-C(t) I)^{-1} C'(t) dt$ and its adjoint is $\overline{\frac{1}{2 i \pi}}  \int_0^1 ((L-C(t) I)^{-1})^* \overline{C'(t)} dt = \ldots$

Comment: since $L^* = L$ we get  $\frac{1}{2 i \pi}  \int_0^1 ((L-\overline{C(t)} I)^{-1} \overline{C'(t)} dt = \frac{1}{2 i \pi} \int_{\overline{C}} (L-zI)^{-1} dz$ and this is still a closed contour enclosing the same eigenvalues, going in the opposite direction, but because $\frac{-1}{2 i \pi}$  became $\frac{1}{2 i \pi}$ it's ok : it is self-adjoint

Comment: @user1952009 have we somehow used $\overline{C'(t)}=\overline{C(t)}'$?

Comment: @user1952009 basically I am not sure why its going in the opposite direction...could you explain it more explicitly?

Comment: yes. finally all the problem reduces to showing that $\int_{C_1} (L-zI)^{-1} dz = \int_{C_2} (L-zI)^{-1} dz$ whenever $C_1$ and $C_2$ are homotopically equivalent with respect to the singularities of $(L-zI)^{-1}$ (i.e. are enclosing the same part of the spectrum) and this is probably the basic theory of the [holomorphic functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus)

Comment: you are right : $L$ is self-adjoint hence its spectrum is on the real line, hence when looking at $\overline{C}$ (the same contour as $C$ but symmetrized with respect to the real axis) it encloses the same part of the spectrum of $L$, but goes to the opposite direction (imagine the case where $C$ is the unit circle)

Comment: @user1952009 Ah thank-you! I think I understand this now.

Comment: are you sure that the spectrum of $L$ can be continuous ? I mean, you are probably in a separable Hilbert space, no ? in a first time you will probably suppose that $C$ is encircling an isolated eigenvalue

Comment: @user1952009 In this case the problem I'm working on explicitly states that $\sigma_0 \subset \sigma(L)\subset \mathbb{R}$ (rather than $\sigma_0 \in \sigma(L)$, so I think that's part of the assumption. It is entirely possible though that the problem meant for me to consider a curve enclosing an isolated eigenvalue..either way I think its a quick fix.

Comment: for the adjoint part it is not a problem, but for computing the residues, it will be much more complicated if $C$ encloses many eigenvalues, even worse if it encloses a continuum of eigenvalues, so it was for you : suppose the simplest first :)

Answer (score 1):

You can always reduce the integral to one around a circle that is centered at a point $\lambda_0$ on the real axis. Then
$$
         \int_{C}R_{z}dz = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(L-\lambda_0-re^{i\theta})^{-1}re^{i\theta}id\theta.
$$
Conjugation, followed by a substitution $\phi=-\theta$ gives
\begin{align}
 \left(\int_{C}R_{z}dz\right)^{\star}
    & = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(L-\lambda_0-re^{-i\theta})^{-1}re^{-i\theta}(-i)d\theta \\
    & = \int_{\pi}^{-\pi}(L-\lambda_0-re^{i\phi})^{-1}re^{i\phi}(-i)(-d\phi) \\
    & = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(L-\lambda_0-re^{i\phi})^{-1}re^{i\phi}(-i)d\phi \\
    & = -\int_{C}R_{z}dz
\end{align}
As expected,
$$
     \left(\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}R_zdz\right)^{\star}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}R_zdz.
$$